# Error when downloading file from server ionic 4

Tags: angular, file, download, ionic4, file-transfer

I am trying to download a file from my server but I keep getting errors. Been stuck for days on this. [image: error]

[image]

HTML

```
<ion-button expand="block" (click)="download()">Download Files</ion-button>
```

TS

```
download() {
    const url = 'http://ccoulter12.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/api/files/5d248f949c71e.pdf';
    const path = this.file.dataDirectory;
    const transfer = this.transfer.create();
    transfer.download(url, path + 'myfile.pdf').then(entry => {
      const url = entry.toURL();

      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        // this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});
        window.open(url);
      } else {
        this.fileOpener.open(url, 'application/pdf')
        .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
        .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
    }
      });
    }
```

Comment: add a `.catch(error => { console.log(error); }` to catch the error coming from `transfer.download()..`

Comment: Done i have edited to include the error message

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is there, its a CORS issue.

I've seen it come up a log but not experienced it myself yet.

As I understand it, this is an issue with your server, it needs to give a permission in the header to allow your file to be downloaded in this way.

You need to research how to do this CORS setting on your server, which depends on the technology used.

The official blog has an interesting introduction to this issue: [Handling CORS issues in Ionic | The Ionic Blog](https://ionicframework.com/blog/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/), and while I've been mostly guessing my way through this answer so far (more... inferring, lol) there is this which backs up what I've said:

> The easiest way to handle the CORS problem is to ultimately ask your API provider to allow all hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Try in real device.

```
download(id, fileName, name) {
  const url = environment.siteUrl+'down.php?down='+id;
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.file.checkDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'downloads')
        .then(
            // Directory exists, check for file with the same name
            _ => this.file.checkFile(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'downloads/' + fileName)
            .then(_ => { this.toastService.presentToast("A file with the same name already exists!")})
            // File does not exist yet, we can save normally
            .catch(err =>
                this.fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/downloads/' + fileName).then((entry) => {
                     this.toastService.presentToast('File saved in:  ' + entry.nativeURL);
                })
                .catch((err) =>{
                     this.toastService.presentToast('Error saving file: ' + err.message);
                })
            ))
        .catch(
            // Directory does not exists, create a new one
            err => this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'downloads', false)
            .then(response => {
                 this.toastService.presentToast('New folder created:  ' + response.fullPath);
                this.fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/downloads/' + fileName).then((entry) => {
                     this.toastService.presentToast('File saved in : ' + entry.nativeURL);
                })
                .catch((err) =>{
                     this.toastService.presentToast('Error saving file:  ' + err.message);
                });
        
            }).catch(err => {
                 this.toastService.presentToast('It was not possible to create the dir "downloads". Err: ' + err.message);
            })          
        );           

    }
}
```